# Sort elasticsearch results on a field which is an array of strings

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am doing a search for some products. 
Each product has an array field called `categories`. 
I would like to order by these categories. 
Furthermore, the categories have hierarchical structure.

Here are some simplified example products

```
product1 = {"categories": ["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo male"]}
product2 = {"categories": ["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo child"]}
product3 = {"categories": ["Pets", "Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo animals"]}
```

such that they become ordered

```
["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo child"]
["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo male"]
["Pets", "Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo animals"]
```

**(Special case)** As a further complexity, imagine we are filtering by `Bath` we would want the order to then become

```
["Pets", "Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo animals"]
["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo child"]
["Bath", "Bath shampoo", "Bath shampoo male"]
```

I have tried adding this sort script to the query.

```
query["sort"] = {
    "_script": {
        "script": "string = ''; count = 0; for (value : doc['@flatCategories'].values) { string = string + value; count += 1} string;",
        "type": "string",
        "lang": "mvel",
        "order": "asc"
    }
}
```

But this seems to sort on the sum of the charcodes not the alphabetical strings

Answer (score 0):

you could add one more field called `merged_categories`, where keep joined string, and sort by it

Comment: ok, but for your special case you could use mix of boosted constant score query, then sort by `[_score, field]`